# MySQL with multiple SELECT and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with my database in mysql. I would like to have a table from my database with `date`, `pat`, `dureeP`, `dureeC` but this function doesn't GROUP BY :

```
select * 
from (SELECT date_format(p.date, "%Y-%m") AS date
            ,p.pat
            ,AVG(a) AS dureeP 
      FROM timing as t, patient as p 
      WHERE t.id_p = p.id_p 
      AND t.pos=6 
      AND t.heure_fin IS NOT NULL 
      GROUP BY p.pat, MONTH(p.date), YEAR(p.datede)
     ) as T1,
     (SELECT AVG(b) AS dureeC 
      FROM timing as t, patient as p 
      WHERE t.id_p = p.id_p 
      AND t.pos=3 
      AND t.heure_fin IS NOT NULL 
      GROUP BY p.pathologie, MONTH(p.date), YEAR(p.date)
      ) as T2
```

With one SELECT I can have what I want but with multiple SELECT I can Group By.
Do you have an idea?

Thank you

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: What does _"With one SELECT I can have what I want but with multiple SELECT I can Group By."_ mean?

Comment: SELECT date_format(p.date, "%Y-%m") AS date
            ,p.pat
            ,AVG(a) AS dureeP 
      FROM timing as t, patient as p 
      WHERE t.id_p = p.id_p 
      AND t.pos=6 
      AND t.heure_fin IS NOT NULL 
      GROUP BY p.pat, MONTH(p.date), YEAR(p.datede)   

With this select I can group my data, but with the multiple select I can't. I know it's a simple case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify your query you might be able to use "**conditional aggregates**" which basically means placing a `case expression` inside an `aggregate function`

```
SELECT
    p.pathologie
  , MONTH(p.date)
  , YEAR(p.date)
  , AVG(CASE WHEN t.pos = 3 THEN b END) AS dureeC
  , AVG(CASE WHEN t.pos = 6 THEN a END) AS dureeP
FROM timing AS t
INNER JOIN patient AS p ON t.id_p = p.id_p
WHERE t.heure_fin IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    p.pathologie
  , MONTH(p.date)
  , YEAR(p.date)
```